# what's the point of tile layers with kml files?

Tags: gdal, tiles, gdal2tiles

By default gdal2tiles will create a bunch of *.tif's and *.kml files. I know that KML stands for Keyhole Markup Language and, in my experience, they're an alternative format to shapefiles, but I don't know why you'd include a shapefile for every tile either...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gdal2tiles creates tiles in either PNG or WEBP format. TIFFs are not supported.

The KML client (the "doc.kml" file in the root directory) and tiles that can be used with Google Earth are created by default when some preconditions are met https://gdal.org/programs/gdal2tiles.html#kml-google-earth-options

> -k, --force-kml
>
> Generate KML for Google Earth - default for 'geodetic' profile and
> 'raster' in EPSG:4326. For a dataset with different projection use
> with caution!
>
> -n, --no-kml
>
> Avoid automatic generation of KML files for EPSG:4326.

PNG tiles are plain image files without georeferencing. The georeferencing info is saved into a sidecar file that is in KML format. When used for this purpose the .kml file is not equivalent to shapefiles but to .tfw world files which are used together with ungeoreferenced TIFFs. An example about a .kml file that describes tile 777.png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>11/1098/777.kml</name>
    <description></description>
    <Style>
      <ListStyle id="hideChildren">
        <listItemType>checkHideChildren</listItemType>
      </ListStyle>
    </Style>
    <Region>
      <LatLonAltBox>
        <north>46.75781250000000</north>
        <south>46.58203125000000</south>
        <east>13.18359375000000</east>
        <west>13.00781250000000</west>
      </LatLonAltBox>
      <Lod>
        <minLodPixels>128</minLodPixels>
        <maxLodPixels>-1</maxLodPixels>
      </Lod>
    </Region>
    <GroundOverlay>
      <drawOrder>22</drawOrder>
      <Icon>
        <href>777.png</href>
      </Icon>
      <LatLonBox>
        <north>46.75781250000000</north>
        <south>46.58203125000000</south>
        <east>13.18359375000000</east>
        <west>13.00781250000000</west>
      </LatLonBox>
    </GroundOverlay>
      </Document>
</kml>
```

The point of KML files is that without them Google Earth cannot show the data. It is easy to test by deleting all *.kml files from the tile directories. Opening the main KML file "doc.kml" with Google Earth will not show the map. The OpenLayers client that gdal2tiles creates does not need the .kml files.